# Unable to load data from a shapefile to SQL Server 2019

Tags: gdal, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

Windows 10; GDAL 3.3.0; QGIS 3.2; Sql Server 2019; ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

When I try to load my shapefiles into my SQL Server no rows are loaded, only the table structure for each shapefile. I've read [Unable to import shapefile to SQL Server 2019](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409290/unable-to-import-shapefile-to-sql-server-2019) and other posts and followed their instructions but nothing happened.

The connection to my SQL Server is Ok, as I mentioned tables from shapefiles are being created with no problem at all. I updated ODBC Driver 17 to the latest version. When I execute ogrinfo this is what I see:

```
ogrinfo "MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}"
INFO: Open of `MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
      using driver `MSSQLSpatial' successful.
1: grillahexpb (Polygon)
2: grillahexpb_utf8 (Polygon)
3: radios_amba_modif_sin_vacios (Polygon)
4: zonas_completa (Polygon)
```

Those 4 are my shapefiles, the utf8 one was one attempt to change the shapefile encoding from windows-1252 (informed by QGIS) to UTF-8, but it didn't work.

This is the last thing I was doing and the debugging info:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}" "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Hexagonos\GrillaHexPB_UTF8.shp" -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI  -a_srs "EPSG:4326" --debug on
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.dll using GDALRegister_ECW_JP2ECW.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_GEOR.dll using GDALRegister_GEOR.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_HDF5.dll using GDALRegister_HDF5.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MG4Lidar.dll using GDALRegister_MG4Lidar.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_MrSID.dll using GDALRegister_MrSID.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_OCI.dll using RegisterOGROCI.
GDAL: Auto register C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\bin\gdalplugins\ogr_SOSI.dll using RegisterOGRSOSI.
Shape: DBF Codepage = UTF-8 for C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\Hexagonos\GrillaHexPB_UTF8.shp
Shape: Treating as encoding 'UTF-8'.
GDAL: GDALOpen(C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\Hexagonos\GrillaHexPB_UTF8.shp, this=000001F6D0EFAF60) succeeds as ESRI Shapefile.
MSSQLSpatial: Use COPY/BCP: 1
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(server=xxxx;database=xxxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server})
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
GDAL: QuietDelete(MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}) invoking Delete()
MSSQLSpatial: Use COPY/BCP: 1
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(server=xxxx;database=xxxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server})
GDAL: GDALOpen(MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}, this=000001F6D0EFC130) succeeds as MSSQLSpatial.
ODBC: SQLDisconnect()
GDAL: GDALClose(MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}, this=000001F6D0EFC130)
GDAL: GDALDriver::Create(MSSQLSpatial,MSSQL:server=XXXXX;database=XXXXX;trusted_connection=yes;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXX;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server},0,0,0,Unknown,0000000000000000)
MSSQLSpatial: Use COPY/BCP: 1
ODBC: SQLDriverConnect(server=xxxx;database=xxxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server})
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table grillahexpb_utf8.
OGR_MSSQLSpatial: Using column ogr_fid as FID for table grillahexpb_utf8.
```

And this is the design of this particular shapefile in SQL Server:

```
ogr_fid   int
ogr_geometry   geometry
wkt   nvarchar(254)
id   float
hexagono   numeric(10,0)
```

And here you have the shapefile and two snapshots, one from the properties in QGIS and the other showing a sample of the data:

[Files in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dql5ndpXCdqH_kLVbpPC6UXwT_hALsG4?usp=sharing)

I'm aware that from QGIS I can generate some SQL code for PostgreSQL that eventually I can use it on SQL Server -at least the INSERT INTO statements- but I want to do it by using ogr2ogr for other reasons (keeping it simple to end users).

**EDIT**:

I downloaded and installed QGIS 3.30.3, edited PROJ_LIB and Path env variables to point to C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\share\proj where proj.db resides, closed the cmd shell and opened a new one and went to C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\bin to execute:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=xxxx;database=xxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}" "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Hexagonos\GrillaHexPB_UTF8.shp" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=ogr_geometry -lco GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY -nln "grillahexpb_utf8"
```

And it gave me this error:

**ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `MSSQLSpatial'.**

When I tried ogrinfo it failed with the following:

```
ogrinfo failed - unable to open 'MSSQL:server=xxxx;database=xxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'.
```

Of course the connection string is the same as before, nothing changed.

GDAL version is now GDAL 3.7.0, released 2023/05/02

Am I doing something wrong or forgot something?

**EDIT 2**:

I've downloaded and installed QGIS version 3.4 and set env variables GDAL_DATA to "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.4\share\epsg_csv" and PROJ_LIB to "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.4\share\proj", closed and opened a command shell in Windows and executed the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=xxxx;database=xxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}" "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Hexagonos\GrillaHexPB_UTF8.shp" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=ogr_geometry -lco GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY -nln "grillahexpb_utf8" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -overwrite -progress -skipfailures -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkb
```

And it did this:

```
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...ERROR 1: Error in fread() reading object of size 168 at offset 18504628 from .shp file
ERROR 1: Error in fread() reading object of size 168 at offset 18504796 from .shp file
ERROR 1: Error in fread() reading object of size 168 at offset 18504964 from .shp file
ERROR 1: Error in fread() reading object of size 168 at offset 18505132 from .shp file
ERROR 1: Error in fread() reading object of size 168 at offset 18505300 from .shp file
100 - done.
```

Though there were errors, all the records in the shapefile were loaded into the corresponding table (verified by a COUNT(*)).

So question is, what are those errors pointing at?

**EDIT 3**

I've found that shapefiles not converted to UTF-8 do not give errors when loaded by using ogr2ogr. The same shapefile converted to UTF-8 gave those errors, and processed as-is did not give any errors, so I assume that something went wrong in the conversion process, so I won't change the shapefiles, there is no need.

Comment: possible solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382314/276

Comment: @Mapperz thank you, will try to download QGIS 3.4.11 (or later) and will comment by editing my post

Comment: @Mapperz sadly there is no QGIS 3.4.11 version anymore for some unknown reason; the latest version available for download is 3.30.3. I will download it anyway and see if it solves the problem with a new GDAL version

Comment: all versions are available here https://download.qgis.org/downloads/

Comment: @Mapperz thank you, I have found the Windows folder right at the bottom of the list, and there are two msi for installing QGIS 3.4.11 (32 and 64 bits), so I'll give them a chance

Comment: Is there a way to change it to Solved?

Comment: You can post an Answer  on your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I posted here was solved by downloading and installing QGIS version 3.4 and set env variables GDAL_DATA to "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.4\share\epsg_csv" and PROJ_LIB to "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.4\share\proj", opening a clean command shell in Windows and executing the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.4\bin> ogr2ogr -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=xxxx;database=xxxx;trusted_connection=yes;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}" "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Hexagonos\GrillaHexPB_UTF8.shp" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=ogr_geometry -lco GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY -nln "grillahexpb_utf8" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -overwrite -progress -skipfailures -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkb
```

And it did the trick, I could load succesfully all my shapefiles into tables in SQL Server 2019.

BTW, I've found that shapefiles not converted to UTF-8 do not give errors when loaded by using ogr2ogr. The same shapefile converted to UTF-8 gave errors, and processed as-is did not give any errors, so I think that something went wrong in the conversion process, thus I suggest not to change the shapefiles' encoding, there is no need and could lead to errors.

Comment: Please post all the details in the answer so other's don't have to skip around looking for specific comments or edits.

Comment: Done! Thank you @Binx for pointing me that